# Why the BindingManagerBase gets removed from the binding

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a very strange case....
We have a user control with a text box, which is bound to a binding source.

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
this.bindingSource.Add(this.viewMode);

this.textBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", "Name", this.bindingSource, OnPropertyChanged));
```

We create an instance of this user control at runtime and add it to list, eg.

```
MyUserControl view = new MyUserControl();
ourViews.Add(view);
```

If we navigate on this view, it gets added to the Form:

```
MyUserControl view = (MyUserControl)ourViews(0);
this.Controls.Add(view);
```

At this point (the first time we do this), the binding works well, the values gets updated in both directions.

Afterwards, some other view gets navigated and the view gets removed from the form:

```
this.Controls.Clear();
OtherUserControlView view = (OtherUserControl)ourViews(1);
this.Controls.Add(view);
```

And somewhen, our old view gets navigated again:
    MyUserControl view = (MyUserControl)ourViews(0);
    this.Controls.Add(view);

And now there is a problem. The binding does not update anymore. We recognized, that the BindingManagerBase of the binding instance is null (we didn't touch the binding since it was created) and the IsBinding property of the binding is set to false. So what caused this? And how we can activate the binding again?

Thanks for help,
Eny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling LayoutControl.UseLocalBindingContext the binding works fine for me.
This property is hidden and cannot be set in the designer. You can set it in code.

I found this solution in the DevExpress-Supportcenter.

Comment: Thanks,your solution is even more nice that setting the bindning context every time manually.

Comment: I've been bit by this bug for the second time now, because I forgot about the first 5 hours of pure frustration it took me to figure this out. Fool me twice...

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing and I've found a different workaround. When you add the user control, back up its BindingContext somewhere (I have a "StackedControl" structure for this). When you remove it, restore it back. This seems to resolve the binding issues.